# VSTO add-in for MS Project: display tasks all at once

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project

The code below (in standard ThisAddIn class of a VSTO add-in) retrieves info about tasks to be added to MS Project (2013) and then adds actual tasks to project Tasks collection. The problem is the Project allowing to add tasks one by one and repainting (refreshing) the project view every time a task is added to Tasks collection. It looks annoying. So far I found and used *Application.ScreenUpdating* property to hide the blinking.

It would be nice to prepare a collection of tasks and attach them *all together* to the active project. Could anyone more experienced please point towards a way to accomplish this? If it's possible at all with the current MS Project Add-In API?

Thanks a lot.

```
....
using MSProject = Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject;
....

public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    ....

    private void ShowTasks()
    {
        MSProject.Project project = this.Application.ActiveProject;
        // TaskInfo is a custom DTO type
        IEnumerable<TaskInfo> dataSource = GetDataSourceSomehow();

        this.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
        this.Application.Calculation = MSProject.PjCalculation.pjManual;

        foreach(TaskInfo info in dataSource)
        {
            MSProject.Task task = project.Tasks.Add(info.TaskName);
        }

        this.Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: A technique you could try, is to add all tasks into a new .xml or Excel file. You could then get automate project to open the file and merge into the active project. This might be much faster and will happen all at once. If you try it, please let us know the results. Does having screenupdating and calculation = False help as well?

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes, I've ended up preparing task data in a file, in my case .csv, and then manually importing it. It goes OK, but it's worth noting that MS Project tries to adjust incoming data rather than silently accepting it. What you've just made me think of is automatically importing the .csv. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some time investigating but was not successful. 
Finally i've received an answer that it's not possible, at least with the current API (MS Project 2013):

https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2014/02/28/creating-and-modifying-ms-project-files-programmatically/#comment-424755